# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator + WSO2 Message Broker

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-message-broker

I need to deploy the message broker. However is not clear if I must have the ESB profile running too.
I'm following this guide https://dzone.com/articles/wso2-enterprise-integrator-with-a-message-broker-p and it seems that ESB profile is needed. Is it correct? What's the point in running ESB profile alongside the MB profile? thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you only need message broker you only need to start MB profile. [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI620/Point-to-Point+Messaging#Point-to-PointMessaging-DownloadandstarttheMBprofileofWSO2EI)

> To start the MB profile: Open a terminal, navigate to the /bin directory where all the startup scripts are stored and run the startup script:
>
> On Windows: broker.bat
>
> On Linux: sh broker.sh

The document you referred explains how to integrate message broker and ESB. You don't have to start ESB profile unless it's applicable for your use-case.

Comment: thank you. Is it possible to have HA for broker? I don't want a cluster, just HA (2 servers with shared filesystem fronted by a load balancer). thank you

Comment: If you only need to have HA with two stand alone brokers without clustering, consider failover configuration provided from client side. it will attempt to connect to first broker and if it's not available it will attempt to connect next broker and so on.  https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI6xx/Setting+the+Connection+URL#SettingtheConnectionURL-Handlingfailover

Comment: in the docs it's specified that MB cluster doesn't support third party load balancing, can you explain why? Can I put a load balancer if I have a failover configuration instead? (2 nodes HA without cluster). @plr thank you a lot

Comment: in a MB cluster load balancing is not needed if properly configured. client is aware about all nodes available in a given cluster and if a given MB node is not reachable client will attempt to connect to next MB node. you can attempt to failover 2 nodes without cluster. But it will be meaning less as subscriber for given queue or topic is not synced through both nodes. But if it's working for your usecase feel free to load balance with 2 nodes without clustering.

Comment: is there any way to sync subscriber via shared filesystem? (like glusterFS or similar). From your reply I understand that a simple HA between MB nodes is not a supported deployment pattern. For multiple nodes the cluster is the way to go, right? Moreover, can you please point me to the documentation, if any, explaining how MB persist data? I mean which are the available possibilities? (DB, filesystem etc). thanks a lot @plr

Comment: Yes. if you need multiple mb nodes with synced subscriptions only way is to cluster the nodes. MB persist data using RDBMS(mysql,oracle,mssql etc.). you can find more info here.  file system based approach is not supported. https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB320/Configuring+the+DBMS+for+Storage

Comment: thanks for your replies, they really helped a lot. I cannot find PostgreSQL in that link, is it supported as RDBMS for the storage of MB profile? Moreover, in my deployment I have wso2 IS and wso2 APIM too, can I share one governance db for every wso2 product and the cluster? one separate config db is already dedicated to the cluster. thanks again